# Disable PLAY button after click - Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, button

I use the following example for playing an MP3 file (I don't need/want "Open" dialog):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.media.*;
        [Embed(source="assets/marseljeza.mp3")]

              [Bindable]
        public var sndCls:Class;
        public var snd:Sound = new sndCls() as Sound; 
        public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function playSound():void {
            sndChannel=snd.play();
        }   
        public function stopSound():void {
            sndChannel.stop();
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup>
    <s:Button label="play" click="playSound();"/>
    <s:Button label="stop" click="stopSound();"/>
</s:HGroup>
</s:View>`
```

After I click on the PLAY-button, the MP3 file plays just fine, but if I click the PLAY-button again, the song starts over from the start simultaneously, and the same if I click the button three, four, five or more times. So I end up with more simultaneously "sessions" of the same song. I want disable the PLAY-button after the first click, and enable the same button again after click on STOP. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question, you can use the enabled property on the button.  Inside your playSound() method, do this::

```
public function playSound():void {
    sndChannel=snd.play();
    playButton.enabled = false;
}
```

Be sure to add an Id to your playButton:

```
<s:Button id="playButton" label="play" click="playSound();"/>
```

You may want to consider just adding a check inside your playSound() method to not play the sound if it is already playing.  To do this, first create a variable:

```
protected var isPlaying : Boolean = false;
```

Then tweak the playButton() method like this:

```
public function playSound():void {
   if(!isPlaying){
    sndChannel=snd.play();
    isPlaying = true;
   }
}
```

In either of the above situations, you'll probably want to add an event listener to the [complete](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#event%3acomplete) event in order to re-enable to button or change the isPlaying flag.  The approach would be something like this:

```
public function playSound():void {
   if(!isPlaying){
    snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSoundComplete);
    sndChannel=snd.play();
    isPlaying = true;
   }
}   

public function onSoundComplete(event:Event):void{
  isPlaying = false;
  playButton.enabled = true;
  snd.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onSoundComplete);
}
```

You can also call the onSoundComplete method from your stop sound method:

```
    public function stopSound():void {
        sndChannel.stop();
        onSoundComplete(new Event());
    }
```

Comment: Hi! After implementation of code above I got following error:"1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1" on line 34...For image look at:[link](http://ubuntuone.com/1gAWXBHFGtgWbmUbmaxSPS)

Comment: You probably need to pass an argument to the Event class constructor specifying the type of event.  In the code I've provided, you can just do new Event('dummy') or new Event(Event.COMPLETE)